# What are the implications of creating an object with a has-a relationship to another object with a has-a relationship to the original object?

Tags: java, performance, object, memory-leaks, reference

The wording of the question is kind of weird. I wasn't sure how to word the question properly, but here's an example of what I'm referring to.

Say I have a class named Student.

```
public class Student {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Teacher teacher;
    private GradeLevel gradeLevel;

    public Student(int id, String name, Teacher teacher, GradeLevel gL) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.teacher = teacher;
        this.gradeLevel = gL;
    }
}
```

In my Teacher class, I want to have all the students that have this teacher.

```
public class Teacher {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private List<Student> students;

    public Teacher(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.teacher = teacher;
        updateStudents();
    }

   public void updateStudents() {
       Connection con = null
       PreparedStatement statement = null;
       ResultSet rs = null;

       try {
           con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, HOST);

           statement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM students WHERE teacher_id = ?");
           statement.setInt(this.id);

           rs = statement.executeQuery();

           students = new ArrayList<>();

           while(rs.next()) {
               Student student = new Student(rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2), this, rs.getString(3));
               students.add(student);
           }
       } catch (SQLException e) {
           students = null;
       } finally {
           rs.close();
           statement.close();
           con.close();
       }
   }
}
```

By adding the Teacher object to the new Student, am I creating a duplicate object or is it just a reference to the original? Is this the best way to do this or is there a better way? What's wrong, if anything, with this approach?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using "this" in Java you are passing a reference to the object executing the code. This means that you are not creating a new object of the teacher for every student, but instead pass a reference of your teacher to your student object. I also don't think there is a better way to approach your "problem". Looks like good code to me. :)
Hope this clarifies it.

(In general, Java follows the principle of assign-by-reference, see [here](http://www.c4learn.com/java/java-assigning-object-reference/) for further explanation.)

Answer (score 1):

No, you are not creating a new object when you pass a reference to the object.

And yes, there are reasons to have mutual has-a relationships. However, in the specific case of students and teachers, I would link them with a third class, the Class. This is because students might have more than one teacher, and a teacher can teach multiple classes of students.

So, Student would contain all the information strictly pertaining to one student.

Teacher would contain all the information strictly pertaining to a teacher.

The Class object would contain one or more Teacher's. It would also contain a List of Student's. In addition, it could contain the information strictly pertaining to that class, for example, the time, the name, etc.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. In my particular situation there is only one teacher per class and one class per grade so it doesn't really matter, but a third "Class" object definitely makes sense and would help.